# Using a function with a different name

Tags: functions

I want to call `tematika-activate` using hooks to minor mode.  But I want to call the function called `tematika-activate` rather than `tematika-enable` which does the same thing, enabling `tematika-minor-mode`.

```
;;;###autoload
(defun tematika-enable ()
  "Enables `tematika-minor-mode'."
  (tematika-minor-mode 1))

(defun tematika-hook ()
  "Activates `tematika-minor-mode' for specific major modes."
  (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'tematika-activate)
  (add-hook 'sh-mode-hook #'tematika-activate))
```

Comment: Why? Aliases are almost always a bad idea: they can be occasionally useful, but you need to justify why in *each* case. And that applies to functions in programs as well as to people posting on SE.

Comment: Did not realise.  How does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```lisp
(fset 'tematika-activate 'tematika-enable)
```

before `(defun tematika-hook () ...)`.

See [10.2.4 Symbol Function Indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Indirection.html) for details.